# Cannot find missing ) in syntax error

Tags: javascript, html

```
document.getElementById('channels').innerHTML = '<li><a onClick="loadChannel('+channelArray[i]+')"><h4>'+memberArray[i]+'</h4><p>Member</p></a></li>';
```

Returns:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Here is the entire snippet:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#vendorMessages", function() {
    var channelArray = new Array();
    var memberArray = new Array();
    pubnub.subscribe(
        {
        channelGroup: getChannelGroup()
        },
        function (status, response) {
            alert("test");
            console.log(status, response);
        }
    );
    pubnub.channelGroups.listChannels(
        {
            channelGroup: getChannelGroup()
        }, 
        function (status, response) {
            response.channels.forEach( function (channel) {
                var channelFormatted = String(channel).split("_");
                var channelMember = channelFormatted[1];
                channelArray.push(String(channel));
                memberArray.push(String(channelMember));
            })
            var i;
            for (i=0; i<channelArray.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById('channels').innerHTML = '<li><a onClick="loadChannel('+channelArray[i]+')"><h4>'+memberArray[i]+'</h4><p>Member</p></a></li>';
            }
            $("#channels").listview("refresh");
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: The error appeared in the console with this remark:  `(function(event){(loadChannel(931_matt))
})` also a big red x next to it

Comment: `loadChannel(931_matt)` see how that's not valid javascript

Comment: try `onClick="loadChannel(\''+channelArray[i]+'\')"`

Comment: One could hardly find a better example of why not to try to build HTML as a huge string, especially when it contains program-like code in an event handler.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> (function(event){(loadChannel(931_matt)) })
> ```

Variables (and function arguments) cannot start with numbers. See [this](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers).

Think of some other way to do this.

Comment: I pinpointed his error, which is enough of an answer; no need to spoonfeed him correct code, he is not an idiot, he can figure it out now.